# Can I use LIKE and >= in the same statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query.

```
$data['incomes'] = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(payment) as total_income FROM drivers_statement where datetime LIKE '$today%' && pay_method = 'cash'")->result();
```

I want to change it to

```
$data['incomes'] = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(payment) as total_income FROM drivers_statement where datetime >= LIKE '$first%' AND datetime <= LIKE '$today%' && pay_method = 'cash'")->result();
```

How can I use greater and LIKE simultaneously?

Comment: What would that even mean? How is something less or greater than something like another? Just set your data to proper dates/timestamps and compare with less/greater than

Comment: what's the data type of datetime in your table?

Comment: Don't you want to use CURDATE() instead of $today%? That way you can compare datetime with datetime

Comment: Why to use a `LIKE` with datetime field?Mysql has inbuilt functions like `TIMEDIFF & DATEDIFF`

Comment: I am quite sure we could help you much better if you explained what you are trying to achieve. You seem to be summing values in a range of dates, so you could also use BETWEEN operator which is kinda elegant. What's your purpose with "LIKE"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it using this.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$first = $first.' 00:00:00';
$data['incomes'] = $this->db->query("SELECT payment FROM drivers_statement where datetime >= '$first' AND datetime <= '$today' && pay_method = 'cash'")->result();
```

Comment: you could also use BETWEEN which is elegant. pseudo-sample:  SELECT blabla FROM blabla WHERE x BETWEEN a AND b. Have fun!

Comment: Thankyou! I will use between :)

Comment: you are welcome. if you belive one answer was actually answering your question, please mark it as a valid answer (accept the answer), so it gets green-V.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use greater and LIKE simultaneously?

Use logical AND operator to check whether both > (greater) and 'LIKE' hold true simultaneously, like this:

```
WHERE x > y AND x LIKE y
```

so I guess something like

```
$data['incomes'] = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(payment) as total_income FROM drivers_statement where datetime >= '$first%' AND datetime LIKE '$first%'  AND datetime <= '$today%' AND datetime LIKE '$today%' && pay_method = 'cash'")->result();
```

would do.

please note I am pseudo-coding and did not try to understand your goal by reading your query and I don't know if this will work. basically I answered the question "How to use a generic operator and another simultaneously" by telling you to use this pattern:

```
WHERE (x OP1 y) AND (x OP2 y)
```

where OP1 is > or >= and OP2 is LIKE, in your case.